# Streaming MKV with seeking

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am sequentially torrenting MKV files & I would like to be able to display them to a client in the browser. The client should be able to jump through all parts of the video that have been downloaded, and buffer when it reaches content that has not yet been added to the file. I have attempted to use ffmpeg RTMP, but that does not allow for seeking from the client. Any suggestions regarding how I can go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am sequentially torrenting MKV files & I would like to be able to display them to a client in the browser.

Look into MediaSource Extensions.

> The client should be able to jump through all parts of the video that have been downloaded, and buffer when it reaches content that has not yet been added to the file.

This seems to conflict with your first sentence.  You're downloading the file chunks in-order, but you want to enable seeking?  Why not download the relevant chunk at the seek location?

> I have attempted to use ffmpeg RTMP

RTMP doesn't work in browsers.  It also requires usage of FLV which has nothing to do with MKV.

> Any suggestions regarding how I can go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Why re-invent the wheel?  Consider using [WebTorrent](https://webtorrent.io/).